# R and RMySQL, how do I get the database name of the connection?

Tags: mysql, r, r-s4

I am accessing MySQL connections from R via RMySQL. 
I found a MySQL command with which to get the database/schema name

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

So I can call this via `dbGetQuery()` to get it from within my R scripts.

However, I also found that calling `summary(connection)` automatically gets the database, among other info.

```
> summary(connection)
<MySQLConnection:(6746,0)> 
  User: root 
  Host: localhost 
  Dbname: my_database
  Connection type: Localhost via UNIX socket 
  No resultSet available
```

Because of the quickness of the result, I assume the connection stores that information within R, but I don't know how to access its contents.

I tried checking its environment, and even looking in the source of RMySQL to understand it, however I don't have enough experience... yet.

So how do I get the Dbname as a variable (not printed)?
Thanks and greetings from Mx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, I don't quite understand why you want the database name as a variable, you can capture it as follows:

```
db_info <- capture.output(mysqlDescribeConnection(MySQLcon, verbose = T))
```

Note the use of `mysqlDescribeConnection()`, rather than `summary`.

The dbname can be accessed as the fourth element of the output vector:

```
db_info[4]
[1] "  Dbname: my_database "
```

If you really have plans to use it as a variable, some string manipulation will be necessary.

```
db <- strsplit(db_info[4], ' ')

final_dbname <- db[[1]][4]
[1] "my_database"
```

Comment: While not a strict necessity, I want to do this is because I want a script to cache the query results from MySQL which are taking longer each time, this is a function of the form `makeCacheQuery(conn, script_or_file)` and inside I check the last time the database from `conn` was modified.  =)

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward:
`dbname <- db.con@info$dbname`

For context, the `@` operator is used to access the "slots" of S4 objects in R.